# How to get local time zone date in swift 3

Tags: ios, date, swift3

I am getting year,month and day from a given date in this way.

```
let today=Date()
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = .current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: today)    

let day=components.day
```

But I'm getting one day ahead from my current day. How can I solve this?

Comment: try `TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")!` for `timeZone`

Comment: @Tj3n but what if I;m 5,6 hrs ahead from GMT?

Comment: maybe because of that you got one day ahead

Comment: @Tj3n yeas I want to get the day related to device time zone

Comment: @user1960169 `calendar.timeZone = .current` is doing that local time conversion.  What is your current time zone?

Answer (score 6):

```
let date = Date().description(with: Locale.current)
print("date ---> \(date)")
```

> Result: date ---> Tuesday, June 20, 2017 at 4:35:15 PM India Standard Time

I'm getting perfect system/local time.

You code is working,

```
let today=Date()
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = .current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: today)

let day = components.day
let hour = components.hour
let minute = components.minute
print("day = \(day)\nhour = \(hour)\nminute = \(minute)")
```

> **Result:** 
> day = Optional(20) 
> hour = Optional(16) 
> minute = Optional(35)

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP asking for an integer day.

Comment: it is giving me one day before  2018-02-14 18:30:00 +0000

Comment: @Chandni I just tested it and it gives me - `date ---> Thursday, February 15, 2018 at 6:09:22 PM India Standard Time`
 `day = Optional(15)`
 `hour = Optional(18)`
 `minute = Optional(9)`

What is timezone for your device/system/simulator? Is follows system timezone and date, on which you are executing this code

Answer (score 1):

Get Local Date and Time

Swift 5:

```
let today = Date()
let timeZone = Double(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT(for: today))
let localDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: Int(timeZone), to: today) ?? Date()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293646-datecomponents):

> If you want “date information in a given time zone” in order to
>   display it, you should use DateFormatter to format the date.

eg:

```
// If date is "Dec 7, 2018 at 6:34 AM" UTC
let today=Date() // is always UTC
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = .current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: today)
let day = components.day  // Is 7
// To print with local version
let myFormatter = DateFormatter()
myFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 3600*10)
myFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
print(myFormatter.string(from: today))  // prints "07\n"
myFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -3600*11)
print(myFormatter.string(from: today))  // prints "06\n"
```

Comment: See also [Date doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date): "A specific point in time, independent of any calendar or time zone."